# jqPlot and naming series

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm trying out jqPlot, but I can't figure out how to set the name of the different series.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', [
        [[201201, 10], [201202, 20], [201203, 30], [201204, 60], [201205, 40]], 
        [[201201, 5], [201202, 10], [201203, 7], [201204, 8], [201205, 11]]
    ], {
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                label: "Year/month",
                pad: 0
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: "Amount (Kr)"
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true
        }
    });
});
```

It renders the diagram, but the series are named series 1 and series 2. Is there any way that I can control the naming of the series?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have names for series you must set 'label' which is under 'series'. [Please see here for documentation.](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Series.label)

[Example code presenting its use is available here.](http://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/26261c90613f8ef0/c1c37b3602359119)